Background images refuse to work on Virtual Studio
I'm just beginning to learn programming, but free trial on WebStorm has expired and I switched to Virtual Studio. For some reason, when I put my past project into it, background images refused to work. Other styles continue to apply and if I switch to background color it works, but images just... don't appear. I checked the links and "Follow link" function leads to the right image, but when I view them in browser (Chrome), they do not appear.
Code examples
css
.title-card{
    color: #591c01;
    background-image: url("/images/brass.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    border-radius: 60px;
}

html
<div class="title-card first-card">Overview</div>

Please share your directory structure for url("/images/brass.jpg")

That would be Programming/newproject/images/brass.jpg. Html and java code are also in the newproject folder and css are in the newproject/styles.
